# Python port listner application / tool

Tags: python

Hi All
I would like to keep a Python application in to a port listener.
The structure is like :
when ever data comes to a port it has to analyse it and return data + associated value determined by the program. 
Is there any good tools / modules available for this

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/):

> Twisted is an event-driven networking
>   engine written in Python and licensed
>   under the MIT license.